# Created logger makes duplicated outputs after raised Exception

Tags: python, logging

**Problem solved!**

By disabeling the flask logger the duplicated outputs seems to have dissapeared.

```
app.logger.disabled = True
```

Seems to have done the trick.

---

Honestly I do not really understand how logger seem to work, but I run in to a strange problem.

I initiate my logger by this code:

**utilities_module:**

```
def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if not logger.handlers:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s",
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        )
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger
```

**Main module:**

```
import utilities
logger = utilities.get_logger("Any_Name:")

logger.info("My heart will go on!")
```

This outputs "YYYY-MM-DD time Any_Name: My heart will go on!" As it should.

**The problem is:**

It works untill an exception is raised and then the output becomes duplicated, but without date and time.

Like this:

```
2018-03-06 15:33:23 INFO Any_Name:  My heart will go on! 
INFO:Any_Name:: My heart will go on!
```

Note the 2 extra :

The logger is created at instantiation of a class and used in the class as self.logger and is only instantiated once.

**Good to know:**

This is a microservice but the duplicated logs are both in k8 and when running it locally, it uses Flask restfull. and those are the pip modules used

```
 - flask == 0.12 
 - flask-restful == 0.3.6  
 - PyYaml == 3.12  
 - Requests == 2.18.3 
 - requests-toolbelt == 0.8.0
```

Comment: Does your exception handler use an instance of logger?

Comment: you are probably seeing the flask configured logger as well: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/#default-configuration

Comment: My exception handler is just simple try: xxx except Exception as e:

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a flask application you could see if removing the default application logger fixes this:

```
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
```

If it does, your flask app is configuring its own logging. Solve this by removing the default handler as above, or by registering your handler with `app.logger` so flask sees you are handling logging yourself.

You could also set the [`LOGGER_HANDLER_POLICY`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#builtin-configuration-values) value in your application config.

Comment: from flask.logging import default_handler *fails*

If I want to use several handlers in different modules do I need to add them all? since I do not have app in the submodules.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

By disabeling the flask logger the duplicated outputs seems to have dissapeared.

```
app.logger.disabled = True
```

Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: you could also set `LOGGER_HANDLER_POLICY='never'` in your application config